# How to display image properly in vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

In my component, I'm displaying the image but in console showing this error `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/null 404 (Not Found)`

**My Code**

```
<img :src="`./uploads/${student.image}`" alt="No Image" style="height: 80px; width: 80px">
```

**Update**

```
<tr class="text-center" v-show="students.length" v-for="(student, index) in 
    students" :key="student.id">

    <td>{{ index+1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.address }}</td>
    <td v-show="student.image">

        <img :src="`./uploads/${student.image}`" alt="No Image" 
           style="height: 80px; width: 80px">
    </td>
    <td v-show="! student.image">No Image</td>
</tr>
```

here in browser showing my image

[image: here in browser showing my image]

in the console showing this error

[image: showing me this error]

how can I remove the console error.??

Comment: student.image does not seem to be set.

Comment: But in the view image showing.. please let me know how can I fix that @RuudVerhoef

Comment: `My Code` is hardly enough to begin to help with the specifics of what you did wrong ... nothing looks wrong in that single line of HTML - but ... what is `student` ... what is `student.image` (clearly it's null) - how is student.image value set (clearly it's being set to null at the moment)

Comment: I updated my question with the picture, `student...` is a single row of my collection `students`, and I call it loop through with `v-for` @Bravo

Comment: your `student.image` is not defined. What is the output of `console.log(student.image)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`student.image` is null, The only way to remove the console error is to first check if image exist by using `v-if`

```html
<td v-if="student.image">
  <img :src="`./uploads/${student.image}`" alt="No Image" style="height: 80px; width: 80px">
</td>
<td v-else>No Image</td>
```

`v-show` will render the html but will be hidden. When you use `v-if` the `html` will not be rendered thereby no error.

Comment: Thank you @kikuyu1 It's work and no error in console thanks this answer. :)

Comment: You are welcome, please accept this answer if it was helpful

Comment: This article will help https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers